# Deal making interface from a menu

Tags: layout, interface

I have an interface where a restaurant owner can create deals from their menu. The way deals are created is as follows:

1. Restaurants can add any number of deal items.
2. Each deal item can offer multiple menu items, out of which the customer can choose one (or more) menu item.
3. The creator of the deal can choose which days to offer that deal on.
4. The creator of the deal can choose a price.
5. A final review, summary and confirmation of the deal is on the following page which is not part of this UI.

For an example, a restaurant can offer 3 pizzas from their entire menu, a garlic bread and a bottle of soft drink. The attached image shows how such a deal could be created.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go for this interaction. Any ideas or suggestions? This is similar to a checkout where you customize a product before you buy, but in this case the level of customization is probably higher.

[image]

Comment: You could display a list with Items the restaurant already sells (pizza your choice, pizza hawaii, pizza hawaii big,...) and when the user clicks on one of theese list entries it displays a big entry with bigger text and maybe a preset image) Make the list entry toggle so the user can click on it again to remove it from the list.

Comment: when you mentioned customer (bullet 3), are you referring to the person who creates the offer, for example the  restaurant owner or employee?

Comment: @gpelelis yeah that's right. Also for no. 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an interaction like the following.
On the left side there is a navigation on top level categories, which as you scroll down or click updates the section on the right.When a new item is added you can show an overlay popup for customization.
On the right side you keep a summary of what is going so far, and what else the creator has to fill (I think I forgot the days section).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7TYNg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This kind of approach creates small goals to complete and let you focus on single tasks. For example:
1. How many pizzas on my deal?
2. *what i am going to add from pizzas?*
3. *ok I want pizza1*
4. System shows popup for customisation , a single task
5. *ok I am done with pizza1, what else?*
6. back to step 1.

When the creator is ok with his products, then he/she can continue with the filling of summary.

Comment: Thanks for this input and it looks like a good solution. However, the problem is that the entire process has to be repeated for however many 'deal items' the deal-creator wants to create. As an example, if the restaurant wants to offer two pizzas from x number of pizzas, and 2 pastas from x number of pastas, these are two different 'deal items'.

Comment: @AdnanKhan so an example of deal could be something like:
"Choose two pizzas from peperoni,margarita,italian and 1 drink from coke,pepsi,water on half price". Also another deal could be only "Choose two pizzas from peperoni,margarita,italian" and another deal could be "1 drink from coke,pepsi,water on half price"
Are those 3 deal valid, or am I missing anything?

Comment: that's right. The restaurant can choose any number of deal items to offer, and any number of actual menu item choices for each deal item. Discounts are on a blanket basis that apply to everything as a percentage of the full price. Thanks a lot for your time and input.

Comment: @AdnanKhan check out the new mockup on my answer. With some tweaks I believe this approach suits better on your problem, than the previous mockup. One of the advantages of this approach, is that the UI becomes almost self explanatory. I hope that this could be another possible solution. Also instead of add, you could use a remove button. Let me know of any other doubts.

Answer (score 0):

How about showing one question at a time instead of all four together. This way the form won't feel difficult to use and you can keep the user focused. Especially for the second question since it look a bit more complicated. As the options are selected you can show the running total in a sidebar.

Comment: The issue is that the process must be repeated x number of times, depending on the deal creator's needs. That number would probably range between 1 - 4, but I can't be sure. This way, a wizard interface would have unknown steps involved.